# Get HAR Data from Remote AJAX Requests with Scrapy-Splash

Tags: scrapy-splash

I'm scraping a web page that makes a number of ajax calls to get data. render.har returns the data that's on the same domain but does not include data from remote domains. Is there a way to get HAR data from requests made to remote domains?

I've tried  the following arguments with no success:

```
endpoint='render.har',
url=url,
har=1,
iframes=1,
allowed_content_types='*',
html=1,
expand=1,
response_body=1,
request_body=1,
console=1,
timeout=20,
wait=6
```

Comment: Adam, I'm running into a similar issue now where I need to access the HAR content from my response but haven't been able to figure out how. Did you have any luck resolving this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no.